# The method areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(double, double) is undefined for the type DecimalComparator

Tags: java, methods, undefined

My main java.

```
public class Main {
    
    DecimalComparator dc = new DecimalComparator();
    DecimalComparator rt = new DecimalComparator();
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            
        dc.areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(1.256, 2.632);   
        
    }
    
}
```

My DecimalComparator code

```
public class DecimalComparator {

    public  void areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(double num1,double num2) {
        
        String Str1 = String.format("%.3g%n",num1);
        
        System.out.println("The value of Str1"+Str1);
    }

}
```

and in Min.class I have error "The method areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(double, double) is undefined for the type DecimalComparator"

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` method is static.  You cannot get a non-static instance of `DecimalComparator` from a static method.  You have to get an instance of your `Main` class to get an instance of your `DecimalConverter` class.

Field names in Java always start with a lower-case character.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.  I made your `DecimalComparator` class an inner class so I could post the code as one block.

```
public class DecimalComparatorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalComparatorMain dcm = new DecimalComparatorMain();
        DecimalComparator dc = dcm.new DecimalComparator();
        dc.areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(1.256, 2.632);
    }

    public class DecimalComparator {

        public void areEqualByThreeDecimalPlace(double num1, double num2) {
            String str1 = String.format("%.3g%n", num1);
            System.out.println("The value of str1: " + str1);
        }

    }

}
```